# Host database with values in Github

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, github, hosting

i am currently working on a webapplication with some friends. All of us need to generate data with a random value generator. It could be awesome if we could host the database in github so each time one of us generates the data, we could pull the main branch and the databases on our local machines would have the same data.

If its not clear what i want let me try to demonstrate it.
Person 1 pushes database with values ABC in it
Person 2 pulls the database, generates data DEF and pushes the data on github.

The values in the database are ABCDEF now and so on.

is that possible or do i have to rent a database server for that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no public facing database server on github.  You can commit SQL files that contain DML to maintain the data and then when you pull run the scripts in your local database instances.  Watch out, though, keeping it in sync can be a nightmare.  Tools like Redgate SQL Src Control and SQL Data Compare can help with that (note that those tools are not free).

Comment: I see! Could you give me more information on how to turn MySQL tables with the data to DML files ? I think synchronizing could work perfectly fine if we dropped and recreated the tables right?

Comment: You either manually maintain the SQL files (writing INSERTS for each row) or use a tool that will automate the generation of the files.  It's not a trivial task and it's far from perfect.  You can quickly get into merge hell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql lite.
https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Just things like merging will obviously not work.
I actually think dropbox might work better than git. Git was meant to track changes, and you cannot meaningful track changes in a binary file.